# Linq query executed from code slowly than from studio

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-2008

I have a Linq-to-Entities query:

```
var result = (from sls in context.tbl_sales
              where sls.saleDate == d
              join clnt in context.tbl_clients on sls.clientId equals clnt.clientId
              group sls.quantity by clnt.distributorId into grp
              select new 
                        { distributorId = grp.Key, 
                          Quantity = grp.Sum(e => e) })
             .ToDictionary(e => e.distributorId, e => e.Quantity);
```

EF generates this SQL query:

```
set @p__linq__0='01.11.2015 0:00:00'

SELECT 
    1 AS [C1], 
    [GroupBy1].[K1] AS [distributorId], 
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C2]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent2].[distributorId] AS [K1], 
        SUM([Extent1].[quantity]) AS [A1]
        FROM  [sales].[tbl_sales] AS [Extent1]
        INNER JOIN [sales].[tbl_clients] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[clientId] = [Extent2].[clientId]
        WHERE [Extent1].[saleDate] = @p__linq__0
        GROUP BY [Extent2].[distributorId]
    )  AS [GroupBy1]
```

This query executed from code and it took about 3-10 minutes to complete.

If I copy the query and run it from SQL Server Management Studio, it takes ~1 second.

Why is it so slow from code?

update:

sql profiler trace result:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
1 AS [C1], 
[GroupBy1].[K1] AS [distributorId], 
[GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C2]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Extent2].[distributorId] AS [K1], 
    SUM([Extent1].[quantity]) AS [A1]
    FROM  [sales].[tbl_sales] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [sales].[tbl_clients] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[clientId] =    [Extent2].[clientId]
    WHERE [Extent1].[saleDate] = @p__linq__0
    GROUP BY [Extent2].[distributorId]
    )  AS [GroupBy1]',N'@p__linq__0 datetime2(7)',@p__linq__0='2015-10-01    00:00:00'
```

update2:
if entity framework generate exec sp_executesql index by saleDate column not workin?

Comment: If you trace that query from code in Sql Server Profiler, what is the execution time? Is the DB on the same machine as application?

Comment: How does it perform when you run the application outside the visual studio?

Comment: query executed as 'exec sp_executesql'